# In C#, how can I make it so it ends .aspx like a directory? Like file.aspx/programtorun/

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've been using php, and switched to ASP.NET because I love it. Anyway... I've been developing my own website and such, but I cannot figure this out for the life of me!

What I have:

```
string val = HttpContext.Current.Request["Header"];
// filename: index.aspx
// what I need to get
if (val == "random")
{
    renderA.Random("randoms.html");
}
else
{
    renderA.Index("index.html");
}
```

What it returns in the URI

```
/index.asp?random
```

What I wish it would look like:

```
/index.aspx/random/
```

Is there someway I can fix this problem?

Comment: are you using webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Global Application Class` to your project (Global.asax file), then you can do the following:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}


void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("random", "random", "~/index.html");
}
```

You will need a reference to `System.Web.Routing`

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

Learn more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0

Answer (score 2):

You should look at switching to an MVC site; it will provide you the functionality you are looking for.

This is from older releases, but you'll get the idea: [Scott Guthrie talking about mvc framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: That same functionality is available to web forms now.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using WebForms and not MVC.  It is called FriendlyUrls and here is a tutorial on [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).  You might want to consider switching to MVC since it can do this using [Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing).

Comment: So can web forms now.